# dhtmlx scheduler: display multiple months on single view

Tags: dhtmlx, dhtmlx-scheduler

I am  using dhtmlx scheduler, Wanted to display multiple months on single view. 
I tried units view But nothing help. 
Is there any ideas to implement that without changing the source code?

Answer (score 2):

1. You can set year view in your app. Also, it's possible to set a required number of months displayed on the screen in this view.
   More info and demo:
   http://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/year_view.html
   http://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/samples/03_extensions/04_year_view.html
2. There is way to create a timeline view with multiple months:
   http://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/snippet/4774ef81
   If you don't need sections in view, you can hide them:
   http://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/snippet/b35f0aad
3. Also, you can create a custom view. But if you need to display a large amount of time - this is not the most suitable way.
   http://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/custom_views.html
   http://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/snippet/aa263cdb